# Show a div in a range of dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, range

How can I show a `div` with a range of dates excluding the year

Example:

```
//check today
$today = date('d-m');

$start_date = '01-04';
$end_date = '30-04';


if ( $start_date > $today && $end_date < $today ) {

    echo 'OK';

} else {

    echo 'NONE';

}
```

What is the best solution to do that in PHP?

Comment: Dates are pretty broad topic. What have you tried?

Comment: what **exactly** do you want to do?

Comment: Hi, i want to know how to show a simple DIV in a range of assigned dates...

Comment: To clarify - what you want is to have a DIV that is only echoed to the browser during a specific date range?

Comment: yes @Dogoferis i need that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try representing your dates in the format "mm-dd". So

```
$today = date('m-d');
$start = '04-01';
$end = '04-30';

if ($start <= $today && $end >= $today) {
    // Today's date lies between the start and end dates
}
```